# How to install downloaded scanner driver

Tags: drivers

When I try to use my Epson 1630 scanner in Ubuntu 15.10, with either Scanlite or Easy Scan software, I get a message saying I need to download the driver from the Epson web site first. 
The Epson web site has both tar.gz and rpm versions of the driver. 
Which one should I use and how do I install it?

Comment: Here is the Detailed Guide on [How to Install Epson Scanner Driver for Ubuntu GNU/Linux](https://tutorialforlinux.com/how-to-install-epson-scanner-driver-ubuntu-linux/).

Answer (score 1):

- First download drivers from http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan_c.html
- Extract the .tar file with - `tar -zxf iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x64.deb.tar.gz`
- move into directory with - `cd iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x64.deb/`
- run `sudo bash install.sh`

`Hope This works !

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I've just noticed my scanner is the Epson 1260 not 1630, so I'll check the Epson web site if that uses a different driver and use the same procedure.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to installing `iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x64.deb.tar.gz` you have to modify two files:

- `/etc/sane.d/epson2.conf`
- `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf`

...to modify the following line in both:

```
net 192.168.1.xxx ### put local printer/scanner
```

With this I solved the problem of not detecting the scanner.